# How to lemmatise nouns?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to lemmatise words like "Escalation" to "Escalate" using NLTK.stem Wordlemmatizer.

```
word_lem = WordNetLemmatizer()

print( word_lem.lemmatize("escalation", pos = "n")
```

Which pos tag should be used to get result like "escalate"

Comment: I think you may have a different sense of *lemmatize* in mind. Most dictionaries will list nouns and verbs (even if spelled the same) as different lemmas, in other words they regard *a look* and *to look* as separate entries. *Escalate* and *escalation* are, according to this view, different lemmas. The NLTK lemmatizers concentrate more on grouping together forms of the same verb (such as *go goes went gone* or *escalate escalates escalated*) or the same noun (such as *escalation escalations*).

Answer (score 1):

First, please [notice that](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html#:%7E:text=Lemmatization%20usually%20refers%20to%20doing,is%20known%20as%20the%20lemma%20.):

> **Stemming** usually refers to a crude heuristic process that chops off the ends of words in the hope of achieving this goal correctly most of the time, and often includes the removal of derivational affixes. **Lemmatization** usually refers to doing things properly with the use of a vocabulary and morphological analysis of words, normally aiming to remove inflectional endings only and to return the base or dictionary form of a word, which is known as the lemma .

Now, if you desire to obtain a canonical form for both "escalation" and "escalate", you can use a summarizer, e.g., Porter stemmer.

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

ps = PorterStemmer()
print(ps.stem("escalate"))
print(ps.stem("escalation"))
```

Although the result is `escal`, but it is the same for both words.